# using ITelephony.aidl to end call is failed on Samsung J6. Require Modify_phone_state permission

Tags: android, permissions, call

I have an APP to end call automaticly using  ITelephony.aidl. It works on almost every devices except Samsung J6. When I try to finish the call, the exception will be thrown casued of  Modify_phone_state  permissin.

Answer (score 1):

If it works, consider yourself lucky.  Google has been removing ways of programmatically ending calls for years, almost as quickly as they pop up.  Its not functionality they want us to have.  If you do have a new way, expect it to be removed.

Samsung's behavior is actually correct.  You aren't supposed to be able to end a call unless you have that permission, which is a system privlidged permission not available to apps without being pre-installed or rooting.